# Where to find application signature/ app key?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am making an app and I wish to integrate it with facebook.

While working on this I came across:

- A name "application signature" which I heard resides in the file debug.keystore and it exists across every application.
- The same app key needs to be mentioned in the field "Hash Key" while creating the app on facebook.

My question is how can I generate/view this key ?

Kindly correct me if I am wrong about something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [key hash for android-facebook app](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a keystore, [read](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) on google dev.
You can signature your app with this keystore

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest way to get this key is enable logging inside facebook library and when your application fails copying this key from logcat output. To do this open `com.facebook.android.Util` and set to true `private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = false;`. Do not forget turn off this back after, because this will can create security issues

Official tutorial with more detailed description and another one way to do this [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig)